# Why does for cycle in vector of unique_ptr require default delete?

Tags: c++, for-loop, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I am working in vs2019 and following code worked fine:

```
std::vector<Foo*> foos;
// fills vector
for (Foo* foo : foos) {
  //do stuff
}
```

However, if i try to use `unique_ptr` like this:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> foos;
// fills vector
for (std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo : foos) {
  //do stuff
}
```

then both vs and compiler are complaining (if I understand correctly) about `Foo` not having default delete. But `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` is used without problems in other parts of the codebase.

Why is this happening and how to fix/circumvent this?

Comment: I can create vector of Foos and create unique_ptr inside the cycle, but i am still buffled why is this happening in the first place

Comment: The compiler should be complaining about the copy constructor being deleted (aka copying a `unique_ptr` is not allowed). The loop tries to copy each vector element hence the error. You can however iterate using a reference to the elements instead

Comment: Change `for (std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo : foos) {` to `for (std::unique_ptr<Foo>& foo : foos) {`

Comment: you are creating coy of `std::unique_ptr` and as name indicates it should be unique. `for (auto& foo : foos)` will do the job.

Comment: `then both vs and compiler are complaining (if I understand correctly) ...` you should always include the error message with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
for (std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo : foos)
```

to

```
for (std::unique_ptr<Foo>& foo : foos)
```

because as mentioned in the comments by @drescherjm and @dave, the compiler should be complaining about the copy constructor being deleted (aka copying a `unique_ptr` is not allowed). The loop tries to copy each vector element hence the error. You can however iterate using a reference to the elements instead.

Answer (score 1):

As comments mentioned, replacing
`for (std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo : foos)`

with
`for (std::unique_ptr<Foo>& foo : foos)`
works (probably problem with creating copies (as mentioned by @dave).